# Displaying an image next to a text using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I would like to overlay a text and an image in a video. I know how to overlay text and an image.
The problem is the text is not fixed, e.g “Sad, “Happy,” “Excited,” etc. I need to show an image right next to the text.

Is there a way to save the width of the text (`text_w`) and use it in overlay for displaying image?

Something like

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex \
  "[0:v][1:v] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2+text_w:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:enable='between(t,0,20)'" \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Not possible like that. But you can position the text in a predictable manner in drawtext, by using `tw`,`th`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard way with 3 steps. Used scale2ref, drawtext, imagemagick trim, xstack, overlay

```
#!/bin/bash
f="input.mp4"
l="logo.png"
t="/tmp/text.png"
o="/tmp/output.mp4"

ffmpeg -i "$l" -lavfi "
color=black@0,format=rgba[b];
[b][0]scale2ref=3*ih:ih[b][v];
[v]nullsink;
[b]setsar=1,
drawtext=text='Some text'
:borderw=2
:bordercolor=red
:fontsize=h/4
:fontcolor=white
:x=(w-tw)/2
:y=(h-th)/2
" -frames 1 "$t" -y

magick mogrify -define trim:edges=west,east -trim "$t"

ffmpeg -i "$f" -i "$t" -i "$l" -lavfi "
[1][2]xstack[o];
[0][o]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2
" -c:a copy "$o" -y

xdg-open "$o"
```